# Strategy for cycling trough preexisting set of variables in c

Tags: c

I’m trying to program a HMI console to read a file from an USB pen drive and display its data on the screen. This is a csv file and the objective is to store the interpreted data to HMI console memory, which the HMI console later interprets. The macros on these consoles run in C (not C++).

I have no issue with both reading and interpreting the file, the issue that the existing function (not accessible to me, shown below) to write in the console memory only interprets char.

```
int WriteLocal( const char *type, int addr, int nRegs, void *buf , int flag );

Parameter:     type    is the string of "LW","LB" etc;
               address is the Operation address ;
               nRegs   is the length of read or write ;
               buf     is the buffer which store the reading or writing data
               flag    is 0,then codetype is BIN,is 1  then codetype is BCD;
return value : 1  , Operation success
               0  , Operation fail.
```

As my luck would have it I need to write integer values. What are available to me are the variables for each memory position. These are preexisting and are named individually such as:

```
int WR_LW200;
int WR_LW202;
int WR_LW204;
...
int WR_LW20n;
```

Ideally we could have a vector with all the names of the variables but unfortunately this is not possible. I could manually write every single variable but I need to do 300 of these…
must be a better way, right?

Comment: put them manually in an array *once,* then index into that array whenever you need to access them.

Comment: Would it make sense to make an array of pointers to int, i.e. int* arr[300] = {&WR_LW200, &WR_LW202, ...}` and the use something like `for (int j=0; j<300; j++) *(arr[j]) = value;

Comment: If they really are all next to each other in memory, you might be able to "force" an array over them: i.e., int *a = &WR_Lw200;  Then a[0] would be WR_LW200, a[1] might be WR_LW_202.  But this trick would only work if they are all defined together.

Comment: @rts1 - You can't trust the memory layout to be that way

Comment: @4386427 Thanks for the tip, this seams to work. Did not know that i could do this with pointers. I will have to read up on this to better understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: @AustinHastings - Because the standard doesn't impose the layout of individual variables in memory. The order of variables stated in the source code has nothing to do with the actual memory layout. The compiler can do any reorder that it find good. So don't make any assumption about memory layout based on the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a look on how it ended up looking:

```
    int* arr[50][5] = { {&WR_LW200, &WR_LW400, &WR_LW600, &WR_LW800, &WR_LW1000},
                        {&WR_LW202, &WR_LW402, &WR_LW602, &WR_LW802, &WR_LW1002},
                        {&WR_LW204, &WR_LW404, &WR_LW604, &WR_LW804, &WR_LW1004},
                        {&WR_LW206, &WR_LW406, &WR_LW606, &WR_LW806, &WR_LW1006},
                        {&WR_LW208, &WR_LW408, &WR_LW608, &WR_LW808, &WR_LW1008},
                        {&WR_LW210, &WR_LW410, &WR_LW610, &WR_LW810, &WR_LW1010},
                        {&WR_LW212, &WR_LW412, &WR_LW612, &WR_LW812, &WR_LW1012},
                        {&WR_LW214, &WR_LW414, &WR_LW614, &WR_LW814, &WR_LW1014},
                        {&WR_LW216, &WR_LW416, &WR_LW616, &WR_LW816, &WR_LW1016},
                        {&WR_LW218, &WR_LW418, &WR_LW618, &WR_LW818, &WR_LW1018},
                        {&WR_LW220, &WR_LW420, &WR_LW620, &WR_LW820, &WR_LW1020},
                        {&WR_LW222, &WR_LW422, &WR_LW622, &WR_LW822, &WR_LW1022},
                        {&WR_LW224, &WR_LW424, &WR_LW624, &WR_LW824, &WR_LW1024},
                        {&WR_LW226, &WR_LW426, &WR_LW626, &WR_LW826, &WR_LW1026},
                        {&WR_LW228, &WR_LW428, &WR_LW628, &WR_LW828, &WR_LW1028},
                        {&WR_LW230, &WR_LW430, &WR_LW630, &WR_LW830, &WR_LW1030},
                        {&WR_LW232, &WR_LW432, &WR_LW632, &WR_LW832, &WR_LW1032},
                        {&WR_LW234, &WR_LW434, &WR_LW634, &WR_LW834, &WR_LW1034},
                        {&WR_LW236, &WR_LW436, &WR_LW636, &WR_LW836, &WR_LW1036},
                        {&WR_LW238, &WR_LW438, &WR_LW638, &WR_LW838, &WR_LW1038},
                        {&WR_LW240, &WR_LW440, &WR_LW640, &WR_LW840, &WR_LW1040},
                        {&WR_LW242, &WR_LW442, &WR_LW642, &WR_LW842, &WR_LW1042},
                        {&WR_LW244, &WR_LW444, &WR_LW644, &WR_LW844, &WR_LW1044},
                        {&WR_LW246, &WR_LW446, &WR_LW646, &WR_LW846, &WR_LW1046},
                        {&WR_LW248, &WR_LW448, &WR_LW648, &WR_LW848, &WR_LW1048},
                        {&WR_LW250, &WR_LW450, &WR_LW650, &WR_LW850, &WR_LW1050},
                        {&WR_LW252, &WR_LW452, &WR_LW652, &WR_LW852, &WR_LW1052},
                        {&WR_LW254, &WR_LW454, &WR_LW654, &WR_LW854, &WR_LW1054},
                        {&WR_LW256, &WR_LW456, &WR_LW656, &WR_LW856, &WR_LW1056},
                        {&WR_LW258, &WR_LW458, &WR_LW658, &WR_LW858, &WR_LW1058},
                        {&WR_LW260, &WR_LW460, &WR_LW660, &WR_LW860, &WR_LW1060},
                        {&WR_LW262, &WR_LW462, &WR_LW662, &WR_LW862, &WR_LW1062},
                        {&WR_LW264, &WR_LW464, &WR_LW664, &WR_LW864, &WR_LW1064},
                        {&WR_LW266, &WR_LW466, &WR_LW666, &WR_LW866, &WR_LW1066},
                        {&WR_LW268, &WR_LW468, &WR_LW668, &WR_LW868, &WR_LW1068},
                        {&WR_LW270, &WR_LW470, &WR_LW670, &WR_LW870, &WR_LW1070},
                        {&WR_LW272, &WR_LW472, &WR_LW672, &WR_LW872, &WR_LW1072},
                        {&WR_LW274, &WR_LW474, &WR_LW674, &WR_LW874, &WR_LW1074},
                        {&WR_LW276, &WR_LW476, &WR_LW676, &WR_LW876, &WR_LW1076},
                        {&WR_LW278, &WR_LW478, &WR_LW678, &WR_LW878, &WR_LW1078},
                        {&WR_LW280, &WR_LW480, &WR_LW680, &WR_LW880, &WR_LW1080},
                        {&WR_LW282, &WR_LW482, &WR_LW682, &WR_LW882, &WR_LW1082},
                        {&WR_LW284, &WR_LW484, &WR_LW684, &WR_LW884, &WR_LW1084},
                        {&WR_LW286, &WR_LW486, &WR_LW686, &WR_LW886, &WR_LW1086},
                        {&WR_LW288, &WR_LW488, &WR_LW688, &WR_LW888, &WR_LW1088},
                        {&WR_LW290, &WR_LW490, &WR_LW690, &WR_LW890, &WR_LW1090},
                        {&WR_LW292, &WR_LW492, &WR_LW692, &WR_LW892, &WR_LW1092},
                        {&WR_LW294, &WR_LW494, &WR_LW694, &WR_LW894, &WR_LW1094},
                        {&WR_LW296, &WR_LW496, &WR_LW696, &WR_LW896, &WR_LW1096},
                        {&WR_LW298, &WR_LW498, &WR_LW698, &WR_LW898, &WR_LW1098}    };
```

Big right? I had consurns that this HMI would have issues with such an approach but it did the job. The code below runs trough a string that comes from the csv file. This code runs inside another `while` cycle to cycle trough the multi dimensional array.
it's a little crude but works.

```
while (i<=5)
        {
            memset(lineTemp, 0, sizeof lineTemp); // clear lineTemp array
            while (lineFromFile[index] != delimiter)
            {
                if (lineFromFile[index] != delimiter && lineFromFile[index] != '\0') { lineTemp[j] = lineFromFile[index];       index++;    j++; }
                if (lineFromFile[index] == '\0') { i = 5; break; }
            }
            index++;
            lineTemp[j] = '\0'; // NULL TERMINATION
            j = 0;

            if (i == -1) {  WriteLocal("LW",temp,3,lineTemp,0); }
            if (i >= 0 && i<=5) { *(arr[x][i]) = atoi(lineTemp); }
            i++;
        }
```

Thanks again for the tip.
Cheers